# Background color transition from one page to the next

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if anybody has a swell solution for the following:
I want the background color of my website to transition from one page to the next. Meaning:
`mypage.com/index` background is **red**. User clicks a link and gets to ...
`mypage.com/greenpage`   background is **initially red and fades to green** after page load. User click a link and gets to ...
`mypage.com/orangepage` background is **initially green and fades to orange** ... and so on.

What I am doing now is:
Save the current background color in the session
`$_SESSION['bg_old'] = $page->bg;`
On the next page, I assign it to the body:
`<body style="background-color:<?php echo $_SESSION['bg_old']; ?>">`
And finally change it with js:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var body = document.querySelector('body'); 
   body.style.transition = 'all 3s ease-out'; 
   body.style.background = bg_new; 
}
```

(I left out some code, but the principle should be visible).
This works, but it feels pedestrian. Has anybody done this in a slicker way?
Can't have any one-page or jQuery solutions.

Thx all!!

Comment: You could use local storage instead of a server side session. But the principle is the same. Only difference is that you store it in the user's browser and not your server. Perhaps a small added advantage to this would be that it can remember the last color for when the user visits your website again some other time.

Comment: @OP I think it's pretty good approach.

Comment: @OP maybe there is some problem if user open multiple tab though.

Comment: @appleapple Didn't think about that. Pretty much means that the only way to make this work flawlessly is to use something like a websocket, so you can push color changes to all windows regardless.

Comment: @apple apple yeah, the colors jump when multiple tabs come into play. Sigh.

Comment: Well with a websocket you could solve that problem. But to be fair, running a websocket just for the sake of some color changes would be a waste of resources, lol. Though if you can adept your project to utilize the capabilities of it, you'll end up with an amazing website

Comment: @JanMirus you may use sessionstorage to store per-tab info (not working if user open in new tab). or you may embed that info in all the links (not working if user not navigate by click).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your approach, as @appleapple pointed out, when you open multiple tabs your colors would jump.

What you can do instead is to save `bg_old` on mouse move (Make AJAX request to some PHP file that saves color inside session. You can minimize the amount of request by sending one request after page loads, then another one after page unfocus and focuses back). And keep rest of the code the same. This way when you open second tab with different color and switch back to the first one transition still would be consistent.

Comment: This would only work reliable in a perfect world where no one uses WiFi or WiFi is 100% stable and there's no such thing as lag etc. By leaving it up to the client, you'll always have this issue. Hence I recommended a websocket and not Ajax. Since a websocket can push without needing a request.

Comment: @icecub but websocket still needs a stable connection.  And how jumping colors issue would be resolved with websockets?

Comment: Because it doesn't need to rely on events. If the connection is lost, it'll automatically attempt to reconnect and the server just pushes the latest known color to all clients (tabs / windows) as soon as the connection is back. So even if you switched to another tab in the meantime or whatever, all of the tabs will remain in sync (as they update regardless of the visitor interacting with them or not)

Comment: Alright but the problem here is not when visitor receives current color but when he sends one. I repeat my question "How jumping colors issue would be resolved with websockets?". If you open tab B and tab A receives push from the server it will set current color as color from tab B. Then if on tab A user navigates to another page, color from tab B will be used as initial color which is exactly the "jump" that OP described.

Comment: No it's not. Like you said, tab A will receive a push from the server to update itself to the same color as tab B. So if user goes back to tab A and navigates to another page, the initial color will be the same color as they left tab A with. Obviously the "downside" will be that all tabs will always have the same color changes. I mean, the only way to have it both ways would be to use a url string query (GET request), so you'll never end up overwriting saved values and rely on data in the URL instead.

Comment: But OP didn't mention anywhere that he wants to keep color of the pages in sync. He just want to transition from one color to another.

Comment: Which is why I made a comment and never answered the question. And all I did was point out that your answer has flaws so you might be able to come up with a better solution. There was never any harm intended nor did I want to come across like some ass or something.

Comment: Thanks shulbix - I love this solution and I thinkt it's perfectly fine to cover a nice-to-have graphic effect with an implementation that's not 120% disaster-proof! May all the users who get badly traumatized by jumping background colors forgive me.

Comment: Sorry @szulbix - typo in your name